# Aqua Data Studio changes encoding of UTF8 file

Tags: utf-8

I have a UTF-8 encoded .sql file. When I try to File-->Open the file in Aqua DS, it throws off the accents, which appears like informaciÃ³n
instead of información (appears on Notepad/Intellij etc)
It behaves correctly if I actually copy the sql from the file and paste it to ADS. Is there a way to correct this?
ADS Version: 8.0.14

Comment: i wonder why somebody would like to close this question without answering? please correct me if it doesnt follow the guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in the later versions of Aqua Data Studio? This works for us.

[image: ADS v13]

Comment: Thanks Tariq, i cant use the 13.0.4 yet, as i dont have the license for that, but will keep in mind.

Comment: Were you able to verify in the latest build? If so,can you select the answer ?